# How volley get updated image from server

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library in my android app for downloading image and I have few things to get clarify on this library .

1. How the library will reflect updated image which is updated at server end on the same image URL , does library will take care automatically ? how does it work ?
2. If library facilited this, what class file I have to refer to see functionality to understand.
3. If library doesn’t have this facility then what needs to be done in order to get updated image at application side.

I hope, i will be receiving answer soon .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Volley` provides any callback which is used when update is done on server side. `Volley` is a networking api which is used to send the data to server.

For receiving updates, you have to implement `Push Messaging` feature. When an update is made on server side, server will send the push message to the application and then application will receive the notification and perform its actions.

Answer (score 1):

Volley maintains a local cache and uses HTTP methods to know if and when the image needs to be reloaded.

This is based on headers like `Cache-Control`, `Expires` (to know when to check for a new version) and [`ETag`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) to make conditionnal queries (this is a way for the client to say "*I already have version XXX send me the content only if it is not the same*")

So the server does not *push* updates, but it controls how often the client will check for updates.

For more details on how Volley handle the HTTP headers you can look at [HttpHeaderParser](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpHeaderParser.java).

Comment: what it means to me is that, volley gives control over cache to set to expire on the time basis, so then it make fresh call to server, isn't ?

Comment: Yes, the expiry date is given by the server : each time an image is download the serveur can add a header saying something like 'this image is valid for 2 hour'. Obviously it only works if the server handle cache-control and / or ETags

Comment: Thank you very much, you made it clear , i didn't know the way it works. one more thing to ask you, does this cache-controller tag set automatically on any modified call (url), let's say, i have given new image to upload at server and the name of the image is same as it before. after placing this in server, does the respective call of this image get update with cache-control tags without any one intervention , or does any body take care of it ?

Comment: The server needs to be configured. For example, I think that for`Apache` the default is to use none. In my case Volley tried In to reload the image each time, I had to add a directive in the configuration. (but it was some time ago and I am not an Apache expert)